# bootstrap with fontAwesome issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I m sonal.
I am designing a website.
In which i m using font-Awesome and bootstrap combine.
But some where confused in linking.

my linking files are:

```
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="../goyal/bootstrap-3.0.0/dist/css/
                  bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../goyal/bootstrap-3.0.0/dist/css/
               bootstrap-theme.min.css">
      <script src="../goyal/bootstrap-3.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



        <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
       <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/
        bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
       <link href="../goyal/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="../goyal/font-awesome/css/font-
        awesome.min.css">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

Where i am lacking. I am in new in this feild.

Comment: You seem to be including both the minified and the full files, that will cause some issues i would suspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue I can see is that you are linking both full and minified version of a few of the files.
Try this instead:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../goyal/bootstrap-3.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../goyal/bootstrap-3.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../goyal/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="../goyal/bootstrap-3.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

The .min.css and .min.js files are supposed to be used in production, they ususaly have shorter variable names etc to make the files smaller, but are ALOT harder to read.
I would recomend linking to the files that are not minified while developing then switch to the minified files when going 'live' with the site to keep the bandwidth down.